# Magnolia fresh installation

Tags: postgresql, magnolia

I am trying to install Magnolia 6.2.17 on Postgres.
I have changed appropriately the "jackrabbit-bundle-postgres-search.xml" to point to Postgres server (tables are create in the DB)

At "**core**" module installation, after bootstrapping **[mgnl-bootstrap/core/config.server.security.xml]** and so after *ObservedComponentFactory: Re-loaded info.magnolia.cms.security.SecuritySupport from node /server/security*,

I have this error (sometimes with '/admin' other with '/system')

```
ERROR info.magnolia.cms.security.SystemUserManager     : Failed to get system user [superuser], will try to create new system user with default password 
ERROR info.magnolia.cms.security.MgnlUserManager       : Could not retrieve user with name: superuser
javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: /admin
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemManager.getNode(ItemManager.java:576) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionItemOperation$6.perform(SessionItemOperation.java:129) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionItemOperation$6.perform(SessionItemOperation.java:125) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionItemOperation.perform(SessionItemOperation.java:187) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:363) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.getNode(SessionImpl.java:1151) ~[jackrabbit-core-2.20.4.jar:2.20.4]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.wrapper.DelegateSessionWrapper.getNode(DelegateSessionWrapper.java:177) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.wrapper.DelegateSessionWrapper.getNode(DelegateSessionWrapper.java:177) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.decoration.ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.getNode(ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.java:120) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.wrapper.DelegateSessionWrapper.getNode(DelegateSessionWrapper.java:177) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.decoration.ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.getNode(ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.java:120) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.wrapper.DelegateSessionWrapper.getNode(DelegateSessionWrapper.java:177) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.decoration.ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.getNode(ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.java:120) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.wrapper.DelegateSessionWrapper.getNode(DelegateSessionWrapper.java:177) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.decoration.ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.getNode(ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.java:120) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.wrapper.DelegateSessionWrapper.getNode(DelegateSessionWrapper.java:177) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.jcr.decoration.ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.getNode(ContentDecoratorSessionWrapper.java:120) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.MgnlUserManager.findPrincipalNode(MgnlUserManager.java:320) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.MgnlUserManager.getUser(MgnlUserManager.java:263) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.MgnlUserManager.getUser(MgnlUserManager.java:242) [magnolia-core-6.2.17.jar:?]
```

Installing Magnolia on embedded H2 is all ok.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Could be there's not enough connections allowed for JR. It needs one DB connection per workspace. Try to adjust this. If it doesn't help, please attach your `jackrabbit-bundle-postgres-search.xml`. Make sure it does NOT contain DB user/password before posting it here ;)

Comment: I'm using JNDI, so i my bundle is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h96Ym0aBIRkZoTCUUvlFBky6N3WVO870/view?usp=sharing

I'm using jndi so, the configuration is 

<Context>
  <Resources allowLinking="true" />
  <Manager pathname="" />
  <Resource name="jdbc/Magnolia" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://webdb02/torrita?loggerLevel=TRACE"
            username="torrita" password=""
            maxTotal="100" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="-1" validationQuery="select 1"/>
</Context>

Comment: Thanks for configs. They look ok. Could you increase `maxIdle` to be equal to `maxTotal` in DB connection config and see if it makes any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue will be fixed in the next release 6.2.18. Please see https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MAGNOLIA-8284

Comment: Ok, thankx.
Do you know a release date for 6.2.18 ?

Comment: ATM I'm being told sometime in the first half of April. So before April 15th.